# How to convert words(numbers in words) into integer numbers in scrapy?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have written this code

```
import scrapy


class YellowPages(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yp'

    start_urls = [
           "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=agent&geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1",
           ]

    def parse(self, response):
        agent_name = response.xpath("//a[@class='business-name']/span/text()").extract()
        phone_number = response.xpath("//div[@class='phones phone primary']/text()").extract()
        address = response.xpath("//div[@class='street-address']/text()").extract()
        locality = response.xpath("//div[@class='locality']/text()").extract()


        data = zip(agent_name, phone_number, address, locality)

        for item in data:
            info = {
                #'page' : response.url,
                'Agent name': item[0],
                'Phone number': item[1],
                'Address': item[2],
                'Locality':item[3],
            }
            yield info 

        next_page_href = response.xpath('//a[@class= "next ajax-page"]/@href').extract()[0]
        next_page = "https://www.yellowpages.com"+next_page_href

        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

But now I want to have ratings added to my CSV file. bt the rating number is written in word.
like this.

```
<div class="result-rating three  ">
```

On the webpage this rating is shown by stars and the number of the total stars is written in word in the code.

I want to get that rating in number. Anyone know how will I able extract the words into numbers??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rating is from one to five, you can maintain an array of these words (one to five) and detect them in the string.

Something like this:

```
word_number_mapping = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
rating_value = None
rating_text = response.css('.result-rating::attr(class)').extract()

if rating_text:
    for k, v in word_number_mapping.items():
        if k in rating_text:
            rating_value = v + 0.5 if 'half' in rating_text else v
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your code extracts the count value. that count value is not the rating value. I want to extract the number which is written in that (class= result-rating three). This three is the rating value. That count value is the number of reviews not the rating value.